# maven with soapui build execution need to junit report

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui

Am new to maven with soapui,

I am looking for a solution to run the soapui build in maven using eclipse as well need maven pdf report.

It's possible if yes please guide me to achieve the execution

1. Need to move my soapui build(Functional + DB Testcase) in my maven project?
   2.what are the plugin is required to config in pom .xml while using soapui 5.3.1/ soapui pro?
   3.while execution the soapui build in maven project it's possible to get the maven report or junit report and pie chart report too?
   4.it's possible to convert in my automation report in pdf format?
   5.need to attach the pdf report in jenkins

Am looking forward your valuable import it would be more helpful to achieve my project completion

Step done:

soapui version 5.3.1

1.Soapui Project name: testmavenproject.xml (which has db and functional test cases)

2.maven project created :

pom.xml file

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.codebind</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-soapui</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

3.Jenkins job created

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a late answer but i advise you to use this step by step [tutorial](http://acodediary.com/soapui-maven-and-jenkins/) it really helped.
As for jenkins integration :

- create a maven job
- configure it on the pom containing the plugin configuration
- In maven goals and options use : com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:test

As a response to your questions :

- your soapui project file sould be added to your maven project
- for a non pro version junit reports are possible but for the pro version you can have other formats. for more details about pro and non pro features check [Plugin Settings](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html).

Answer (score -1):

1) add soupui maven pulgin pom.xml

```
        <!--Add the repository for where Maven can find the soapUI Plugin-->
        <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eviwarePluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
        <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>eviware</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
        <!--This is the version of soapUI to grab from plugin repo-->
        <!--At the time of writing the 3.0.1 plugin had not been created-->
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <!--The location of your soapUI setting file-->
            <projectFile>/home/test/test.xml</projectFile>
            <!--Where to place the output of the run-->
            <outputFolder>/home/test/output/</outputFolder>
            <!--Make the jUnit results file-->
            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>soapUI</id>
            <!--Run as part of the test phase in the Maven lifecycle-->
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <!--Run the test phase of eviware:maven-soapui-plugin-->
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>
```

2)  run the soapUI tests by calling "mvn eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:test"

more detail: http://blog.karit.geek.nz/2009/08/using-soapui-to-do-testing-as-part-of.html